# How to test Spring event listener conditional SpEL?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, events, mockito, spring-test

I have a working annotation driven event listener with a conditional statement. But even though the code works fine, I'm not able to unit test this conditional due to a failure in the test case processing the SpEL condition.

I noticed that this error only occurs for Spring Boot 1.5.x version, as 2.1.x version worked as expected. Unfortunately I need to use the 1.5.x version.

Class handling the event:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyComponent.class);

    @EventListener(condition = "#createdEvent.awesome")
    public void handleOrderCreatedEvent(OrderCreatedEvent createdEvent) {
        LOGGER.info("Awesome event handled");
    }

}
```

The event class:

```
public class OrderCreatedEvent {

    public OrderCreatedEvent(boolean awesome) {
        this.awesome = awesome;
    }

    private boolean awesome;

    public boolean isAwesome() {
        return awesome;
    }
}
```

My test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyComponent.class)
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;
    @MockBean
    private MyComponent myComponent;

    @Test
    public void handleOrderCreatedEvent_shouldExecute_whenAwesome() {
        OrderCreatedEvent event = new OrderCreatedEvent(true);
        publisher.publishEvent(event);
        verify(myComponent).handleOrderCreatedEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Full source code can be found here: https://github.com/crazydevman/spring-event-testing

Running the application everything works as expected. However, when running the test case I keep getting this error:

`org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'awesome' cannot be found on null`

Debugging the code, it looks like this is due to SpEL not being able to interpret the method parameter name 'createdEvent' for the mocked bean, but I don't know how to fix it.

Is there a way to unit test the event conditional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyComponent.class);

    @EventListener(condition = "#root.args[0].awesome")
    public void handleOrderCreatedEvent(OrderCreatedEvent createdEvent) {
        LOGGER.info("Awesome event handled");
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: That's fixed the issue for me too, but why doesn't it like `createdEvent` parameter name?